# Python script execution returns null to textblock in wpf

Tags: c#, python, wpf

I've looked through lots of questions about this, but I still can't figure out what's going on in my code. I have a simple form, with a browse button so you can pick a script to run. You then press run, and the output of the script populates into a textblock.

Right now, I'm running a python script that is simply:`print "Hello World"`.

Here's my code to pick up the output:

```
var proc = new Process
  {
     StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
     {
          FileName = "python.exe",
          Arguments = script,
          UseShellExecute = false,
          RedirectStandardOutput = true,
          RedirectStandardInput = true,
          RedirectStandardError = true,
          ErrorDialog = true,
          CreateNoWindow = true //no black window
      }
   };

proc.Start();
string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
test.Text = output; //This is the textblock
```

What happens is that the textbox content changes to blank. No output is showing, just blank. This is pretty straightforward and super frustrating that I can't figure this out. Why is it returning null?

Answer (score 1):

You are starting a new Process to get the output, but there can be a delay in the process to fetch output. Thus the string output is null and is stored in the TextBox. Make sure that output is printed only when the process is completed.

Comment: If I do a proc.WaitForExit(); then afterwards capture the output with StandardOutput, I still get a null string